# Resign apple store IPA with developer certificate

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipa

I am trying to resign an apple store .ipa with my developer certificate using iResign. It resigns the .ipa but does not install on iPad. Any idea why it's not working? Any workaround?

Thanks in advance
Ranjan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AppStore apps are encrypted - you'd need to decrypt it before re-signing and installing it.

If you re-sign an appstore/encrypted app, you essentially change it to developer/ad hoc/enterprise and it simply doesn't run. As of iOS7 it would fail with:

> AppleFairplayTextCrypterSession::fairplayOpen() failed, error -42022

Comment: sorry, no links, these are just my observations